# Xamarin Android Local Notification

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android

i am using API Level 10 (Xamarin.Android v2.3 support) in project

Assembly reference missing error.

In Main Activity

Button click handler is having following code

```
        Bundle valuesForActivity = new Bundle();
        valuesForActivity.PutInt("count", _count);

        // Create the PendingIntent with the back stack
        // When the user clicks the notification, SecondActivity will start up.
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
        resultIntent.PutExtras(valuesForActivity); // Pass some values to SecondActivity.

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
        stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(SecondActivity)));
        stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        // Build the notification          
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .SetAutoCancel(true) // dismiss the notification from the notification area when the user clicks on it
            .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent) // start up this activity when the user clicks the intent.
            .SetContentTitle("Button Clicked") // Set the title
            .SetNumber(_count) // Display the count in the Content Info
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.monoandroidsplash) // This is the icon to display
            .SetContentText(String.Format("The button has been clicked {0} times.", _count)); // the message to display.

        // Finally publish the notification
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify(ButtonClickNotificationId, builder.Build());

        _count++;`
```

getting error for the

`TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);`

AND

`NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)`

Errors are Missing Assembly reference and `TaskStackBuilder`  Does not exist

i am not getting what is missing in assembly reference 
Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Its a late reply, but may help others.

The problem you have mentioned is happening because of version (lower) of Mono.Anroid

In lower version (such as 4.2), the Android.App.TaskstackBuilder namespace is missing.
Upgrading the Mono.Android may solve the problem.